# Committing failed from Egit eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, github

I am trying to commit my stuff to github from eclipse on ubuntu. But I get the message:

```
Committing changes has encountered a problem. 
Committing failed
Prepairing trees /var/www/project/public/.htaccess.save (permission denied)
```

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a simple Access Right issue, as [seen in other instances](http://www.paulsohier.nl/blog/2007/12/02/updating-a-phpbb3-rc3-to-rc8/).
Maybe `.htaccess.save` is part of your Git repository, while in fact it shouldn't?
If that is the case, you could

- first `git rm` it (after saving it), and commit a new revision without that directory
- add the directory to your `.gitignore` file
- restore the `.htaccess.save` directory.
- try to push to GitHub.

Comment: hi, I think I have same issue. Is .htaccess.save related to rsync ? Or is just benerated by a repository ? Can I delete it, and run rsync again ?

Comment: @Patrick: I am not sure `htaccess.save` is linked to `rsync`, but you should be able to remove it and run `rsync` (move that file elsewhere just to be on the safe side)

Comment: Yeah thanks, I've done it. I was wondering if rsync is storing invisible files into the synched directories. I'm asking this because I'm going to copy the files into a svn directory and I'm afraid to lose rsync configuration invisible files.